# Compile thread program

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have made a simple program in C that uses threads.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>

//Global mutex variable
pthread_mutex_t     mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
//Shared variable
int x=100;

//Thread function
void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
    //Aquire lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf ("Thread has aquire lock!\nIncrementing X by 100. . .\n");
    x+=100;
    printf ("x is %d \n", x);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return NULL;
}

//Main function
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ 
    pthread_t     threadid;
    //creating thread
    pthread_create(&threadid, NULL, threadfunc, (void *) NULL );
    //Aquire lock
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    printf ("Main has aquire lock!\ndecrementing X by 100. . .\n");
    x-=100;
    printf ("x is %d \n", x);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile it, I get an error of "undefined reference to pthread create". I am using this command for compilation:

```
gcc -lpthread thread.c -o thr
```

Comment: Some systems require `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `-lpthread` *after* the `thread.c`.  gcc is looking for library methods to satisfy the linking requirements it's already seen when it looks at a library, so when you put the library first, it doesn't find anything it needs out of pthread and ignores it.